# SUMO Reward Points Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to know what tables and fields it is using to assign Enable SUMO Reward Points->Enable, Reward Type->By Percentage, I don't want to do this manually for more than 3000+ existing Products/Categories, I just want to create a PHP script to assign these values on existing Products/Categories, Any PHP Script/SQL Query in reply will be much appreciated.. TIA
Referring to this plugin:
[Plugin URL](http://codecanyon.net/item/sumo-reward-points-woocommerce-reward-system/7791451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, There's an option of Bulk Update in SUMO Plugin itself, which will update all the existing Products/Categories value according to plugin options...